# Can I use 'in' to update field instead of '=' in SQL oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, list, sql-update

I'm working on a project where I have to update multiple records in the same column. My values are stored in the list same as ID's that I have to use in my WHERE clause. I was wondering if I can use 'IN' instead of '=' and update all values from my list? Here is my code for lists:

```
<cfset listUserNum = ArrayToList(userNum)>
<cfset listUserCode = ArrayToList(userCode)>
```

They look like this:

```
listUserNum = "72,15,71,27,16,14,22";
listUserCode = "B,B,C,T,R,M,Y";
```

Here is my update statement:

```
<cfquery name="UpdateUsers" datasource="test">
    Update Users
    Set UserCode in <cfqueryparam value="#listUserCode#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="yes" /> 
    Where UserNumber in <cfqueryparam value="#listUserNum#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="yes" /> 
</cfquery>
```

I used 'IN' for my WHERE clause in the past but I never used in my SET. Let me know if I'm doing something wrong here or if there is better way to do this. I still haven't tried this because I have to update around 20k records and I want to make sure this is the best way before I run my update. Thank you!

Comment: No - you can only set a field to a single value, so `in` makes no sense.  Create a temporary table (or a static table if the lookup rarely changes) with two columns, then join to that table in the update.

Comment: I can not use temporary tables in my project. That's way I have to use lists and try to update my records this way. What would be the other option then? Thank you.

Comment: You _could_ do a massive union in a subquery to create a quasi- temporary table.

Comment: @DStanley I never done that before. Can you provide any example for that please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table to house that mapping and join to it in your `UPDATE`:

```
Update u
Set UserCode = l.UserCode
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Lookup l
  ON u.UserNumber = l.UserNumber
Where UserNumber in <cfqueryparam value="#listUserNum#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If a temporary table is no option, I would just run 20K updates instead of trying to compress it into one statement. Any decent database should have no problem processing that.